# Android app bug reporting

Tags: android, acra, bug-reporting

I am aware that there are many bug reporting tools, such as [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), that can generate content-rich crash reports.

But my question is: Is it possible to identify bugs that don't cause a crash? For example, I got this user feedback for my app:

> Images are very low quality, zoom in to a blurry pixelation because you don't load the full sized image.

This bug doesn't cause a crash; in that case, how can I catch them to improve my app? Because if the user doesn't complain, I am unaware of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You need some way in your code to detect it and send an event. Google Analytics, for example, [allows you to send custom events to your analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events), but they still have to be generated by your code:

```
public void loadImageToView(ImageView iv) {
    if (/* some criteria */)
        myTracker.sendEvent("bug_report", "image_load", "failed", /* some optional value */);
    // ...
}
```

You could add a feature in your app that allows user feedback which could send device information as well, but I think that's the best you can do. There is no way to auto-detect  bugs in your app.

**Further reading:**

- [Google Analytics for Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/)
- [Tracking User Behavior with Google Analytics SDK for Android](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/tracking-user-behavior-with-google-analytics-sdk-for-android/)

Answer (score 3):

ACRA can be used to report [unexpected application state](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception) as well as Google Analytics but you must do detection on your own.

When unexpected situation is detected it may be reported like this:
`ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(new IllegalStateException("Low image quality: "+imageUrl));`

Answer (score 0):

[Google Mobile App Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/mobile/) can report it as an [Event](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en-GB)

```
String approxSize=.... //"100K", "500K", "1M"
EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(context);
easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Warning", "Poor quality image", approxSize, 0L).build());
```

I also report nearly all caught exceptions as an Analytics event - [details](http://tekkies.co.uk/report-caught-exceptions-as-google-analytics-events/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Bugclipper](http://www.bugclipper.com). Its exactly the thing you are looking for. It allows users/testers to report issues or share feedback from within the app. It allows screenshots and screen recordings with voice. Works good for  beta testing of Android & iOS apps.

p.s. - I am one of the founders of Bugclipper.